# Magmi import: Add To Cart Button not showing

Tags: magmi

I have managed to make a csv which imports my products using magmi into my magento store. All works well but the buy now buttons don't appear unless I go to the product and click save. I've tried reindexing or clearing the cache but nothing seems to work. Any further ideas. The same happens when i send an update import.
I'm using the up to date magento/magmi.

Hi,
I'm using this sample. I've already tried to update an randomly attribute of many products, to act like an "mass save", but it won't works too.

Answer (score 1):

The 'add to cart' button will disappear if you let Magento manage stock / when the item is out of stock. Did you define is_in_stock and manage_stock in your header?

Comment: Thanks for your time.

I'm sending the stock import this way:

qty, 1| use_config_manage_stock, 1| manage_stock, 0| is_in_stock, 1

http://screencast.com/t/qCPAPCDG
I'm using management stock no, as default in my store.

I found another way to solve this probem, i'm sending an standart import to magento, with the sku and status columns, Its working, but yet not what I seek, I would like the Magmi do this without the need to import another file.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In `Catalog > Manage products`. Select all or the ones you want. Action : `Modify attributes`.
Set

```
Catalog-> Manage Products-> X product-> Design-> Display Product Options In: to Product Info Column
```

Worked for me